# Is there a way or tool that push cassandra data into AWS for backup purpose?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cassandra, database-backups, priam

I'm working as cassandra cluster DevOps engr. wanted to know is there a way or tool that push cassandra data into AWS for backup purpose.I have cassandra cluster that is not in AWS. I explored netflix-priam but as per my understanding it needs cassandra to be hosted on AWS itself then it takes backups on EBS. my question is why i need to install cassandra cluster on AWS if i already have on-premise working cassandra. I have also read about cassandra-snapshotter & table-snap code in github,but dont want to use that. So again asking, is there such tool other than tablesnap,cassandra-snapshotter & Netflix-priam ??

Please help
Thanks

Comment: looking at cassadra-snapshotter: https://github.com/tbarbugli/cassandra_snapshotter it seems to be exactly what you need to. Can you please give reasons why you cannot use this and then others can help guide you to a suitable suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: https://www.rubrik.com/solutions/cassandra/ might be worth exploring

Comment: @markc : i don't want to use  cassandra-snapshotter because it doesn't have GUI based solution.

Comment: @markc: Also as per my undersatnding, **cassandra-snapshotter** takes snapshot first, then send data to AWS S3. By taking snapshot it'll occupy local space which i dont want to. Please guide if i'm wrong

Comment: @ParulChourasia - correct it does take a snapshot and this is the _only_ way to backup. You do not want to try copying live sstables which could be compacted away from "under the nose" of your backup process. Snapshots will not take up more room because they are hard linked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771

Comment: thanks for the answer @markc i'll try this.